# The sha module is deprecated

Tags: python, sip, centos6, sha, hashlib

I am playing with SIPVicious (python)

So I have a dedicated server centos 6.6. When I run the script, I get this error:

> /root/1/fphelper.py:134: DeprecationWarning: the sha module is deprecated; use the hashlib module instead
>
> import sha, re

When I used this command.

> rpm -qa | grep python

Here is what was appeared:

```
rpm-python-4.8.0-38.el6_6.x86_64
dbus-python-0.83.0-6.1.el6.x86_64
gnome-python2-2.28.0-3.el6.x86_64
gnome-python2-canvas-2.28.0-3.el6.x86_64
libreport-python-2.0.9-21.el6.centos.x86_64
gnome-python2-applet-2.28.0-5.el6.x86_64
gnome-python2-gconf-2.28.0-3.el6.x86_64
gnome-python2-bonobo-2.28.0-3.el6.x86_64
python-urlgrabber-3.9.1-9.el6.noarch
python-tools-2.6.6-52.el6.x86_64
newt-python-0.52.11-3.el6.x86_64
python-ethtool-0.6-5.el6.x86_64
python-pycurl-7.19.0-8.el6.x86_64
python-docs-2.6.6-2.el6.noarch
gnome-python2-libegg-2.25.3-20.el6.x86_64
python-iwlib-0.1-1.2.el6.x86_64
libxml2-python-2.7.6-17.el6_6.1.x86_64
gnome-python2-gnome-2.28.0-3.el6.x86_64
python-iniparse-0.3.1-2.1.el6.noarch
gnome-python2-libwnck-2.28.0-5.el6.x86_64
libproxy-python-0.3.0-10.el6.x86_64
python-2.6.6-52.el6.x86_64
gnome-python2-gnomevfs-2.28.0-3.el6.x86_64
gnome-python2-desktop-2.28.0-5.el6.x86_64
gnome-python2-extras-2.25.3-20.el6.x86_64
abrt-addon-python-2.0.8-26.el6.centos.x86_64
at-spi-python-1.28.1-2.el6.centos.x86_64
python-libs-2.6.6-52.el6.x86_64
python-devel-2.6.6-52.el6.x86_64
```

Please help me how to fix this.

Comment: This is a warning, not an error.

Comment: and is there any methods to remove it and why it appeared i used this script before and this warning never appeared

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are receiving this *warning* since there was a change in Python standard library. The functionaliy of the `sha` module has been merged with other hash algorithms into the `hashlib`. The warning notifies you that the old module is used by the code and that it should be changed to the new library.

See https://docs.python.org/2/library/hashlib.html on how you can change your code to use the `hashlib`.