# Python SHA to hashlib

Tags: python, sha, hashlib

I am updating some old code and there are a lot of the [long depreciated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31220068/14990454) `sha` module calls such as:

```py
sha.new(borne.mark).digest()[:4]
```

and many others among the code.

Since I am converting it to modern code, I want to assure compatibility, while using the `hashlib` package, but I'm not sure which `sha` to use, as the [oldest documentation](https://docs.python.org/fr/2.7/library/hashlib.html) is already too recent and does not mention the older version. Is the one to use just `hashlib.sha1()`?

I have spotted several potential `sha` to use from `hashlib` but I'm not sure which one to use to match the former `sha` lib.

Comment: Older docs: https://www.python.org/doc/versions/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears the algorithm used is `sha1`.
Source: [python 2.5 documentation](https://docs.python.org/release/2.5/lib/module-sha.html)